# Keyboard Key holder on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, console

I need a code that when inserted in the Browser Console, on an active webpage, in the class = "_nv7oj6" , will hold a key ("A" for example) for unlimited times.

This is quick code my friend made to keep on clicking on a button from the page:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("_sl2x43m")[0];
setInterval(function(){ button.click();}, 800);
```

I want something similar, but which will insert a letter, unlimited times.
Thanks a lot !

---

Here is a screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can i get some help here ?

Comment: append the letter to a div

Comment: I don't know, that's why I am here... And thanks a lot for helping me Evik.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```js
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("_sl2x43m")[0]; 
setInterval(function(){button.click();},800);
function AddLetter(){
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("_nv7oj6");
div[0].innerHTML += "A"
}
```

```html
<button class="_sl2x43m" onClick="AddLetter();">Im clicking myself</button>
<div class="_nv7oj6"></div>
```

**(UPDATE ON YOUR COMMENT) OR JUST DO:**

```
 setInterval(function(){
document.getElementsByClassName("_nv7oj6")[0].innerHTML += "A";
 },800);
```

Comment: I opened the console (CTRL+SHIFT+J) I paste them but not working